# ElFinder:Get the path of file selected on the server side

Tags: filepath, elfinder

Is it possible to get the path of file selected, on an elFinder instance,on the Server side.?
I tried getting it on the client side and was able to get it as follows:

```
handlers : {
select : function(event, elfinderInstance) {
var path=elfinderInstance.path(selected[0]);
}
```

Is it possible to get the path in connector.php?

Comment: Can you provide the `connector.php` so we can take a look at it? It would also be helpful if you can tell us where you need the file path? Also, take a look at the following wiki info https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-Server-API-2.0

Comment: The connector.php is the same as that one in github.
Here is the link https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/blob/2.x/php/connector.php